# Similar heroes/champions to Kennen (from League of Legends) in DOTA2?

Tags: league-of-legends, dota-2

The character [Kennen](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Kennen_The_Heart_of_the_Tempest) really agreed with me in League of Legends. Now that I'm starting to play DOTA2, are there any equivalents?

**Edit**
I play him usually as AP but very aggressively (harassing)...

Comment: can u specify your playstyle? AP or AD or even hybrid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well lets define Kennen:

- He is fast;
- He has a lot of nuke;
- He can stun;
- He can carry;
- He has a good escape mechanism.

I don't think there is a equivalent hero in DotA 2 but I would recommend the following:

1. Mirana:

   - She has a skillshot+stun (but high CD);
   - She has a leap (escape mechanism);
   - She can become invisible (and her team too);
   - She can carry with a lot of farm;
   - She has a significant nuke (AOE and stun).
2. Weaver:

   - Feels like Kennen since he can get invisible with low CD and gets very fast;
   - Has no stun;
   - No skillshot;
   - Can carry the game with ease (one of the most picked carries);
   - If he gets his core item (radiance) early he dishes out a lot of AOE too which feels like kennen).

There are many more that have the features that I defined for Kennen but they have a totally different feeling/playstyle (Zeus can spam spells like Kennen and nukes hard but cannot carry in late game and has no escape mechanism on his own).

PS: Kennen is an hero that can harass easily. You will not find many chars in DotA or DotA 2 in particular that can spam spells like many heroes in LoL can. That's why you should drop the wish to play a harass-heavy char that has an AOE nuke + escape + carry potential.

Comment: Think your last point might sum up how I play (or what I'm looking for)...unfortunately...

Comment: man, fast, nuke, stun, carry, AND good escape?  I wish there was someone like that in Dota 2 :P

Comment: An addition to the answer: Now Dota2 have Skywrath Mage. He got awesome nuke, low CD, slow with huge range, can carry and can have escape if you get him a blink or force. If the main point is nuking, he's awesome.

Comment: only 2 out of 5 criteria is not enough in my opinion. blink and force are obv escape options on any hero.

Answer (score 4):

I don't play League, so I may not get his playstyle right, but I'm generally pretty good at getting an accurate grasp on how characters play just from a textual description.

Kennen looks like a cross between Weaver and Razor. As you should know by now, the concept of an "AP carry" doesn't really exist in Dota2, so already it's going to be hard to match. Also, ranged carries in Dota2 very rarely have strong disables, usually either having slows or difficult skillshots.

Razor:

- A powerful ganker and **midgame** carry who builds tanky items because one skill provides most of the damage that he needs to do well.
- Comparatively weak lategame carry because of his terrible AGI growth and lack of scaling skills.
- Typically rushes Vanguard and/or Hood, depending on the enemy team, followed by a Manta Style and then Heart/BKB/Lifesteal/DPS as needed.
- Ultimate is very similar to Kennen's.
- AoE nuke, fast, but no crowd control or disables.

Weaver:

- He carries, but his lategame potential is kind of lacking, he needs more gold to deal damage than other lategame carries like Spectre, Void, or Anti-Mage.
- Typical item build relies on a fast Vanguard into Radiance to give him burst-survivability and to allow him to put out big AoE damage by being hard as hell to kill in teamfights.
- Shukuchi is very similar to Lightning Rush.
- Geminate Attack is similar to Electrical Surge's passive.

Other heroes you might want to look into: Windrunner, Viper, and Morphling. If you're fine with not being much of a carry, consider Shadow Demon and Batrider who both deal with the "charges" aspect of Kennen to deal damage.

Comment: i thought about razor too but since he has no stun and no real escapemechanism(except the ms buff) i didnt mention him. windrunner and morph are good calls! PS: while there is no "AP-Carry" nuker can still dominate the mid and lategame. qop and puck can destroy the enemy team with lvl advantage and farm (and thats what those heroes should try to archive in every game when played as mid)

Comment: They can do well in midgame but the game needs to essentially be over for any INT hero to win lategame. Heroes like Leshrac, Necrolyte, and Krobelus are common picks to carry midgame with their spells.